# onPerformSync() is not triggered after ContentResolver.requestSync() call

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I am trying to implement sync adaptor, I have followed [This guide.](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html)

But  onPerformSync() is not triggered after ContentResolver.requestSync() call .

I have also tried some other tutorials and tried to run their code, but still same issue.

Please tell me does I need to do some extra configuration for this.

My code of triggering sync operation is as folows :

```
 Account newAccount = new Account(GlobalInfo.ACCOUNT, GlobalInfo.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) this.getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
    accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount, null, null);

ContentResolver.requestSync(newAccount,GlobalInfo.AUTHORITY, Bundle.EMPTY);
```

Please guide me to solve this issue.

EDIT : 
Accounted created (in Settings -> Accounts and Sync settings) by above code showing **sync is off**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the flags in the third parameter of requestSync instead of passing an empty Bundle? From what I understand you will need to set at least the ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL and ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED. The later sill tell the SyncManager to run the sync job right away instead of waiting.

Answer (score 0):

It is also required to have internet connection to trigger. If there is not internet. it wont execute.